# Api fetch -No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, cors, fetch

i have been getting those errors from past two days when getting data from apis sometimes it work ok and most of the time i am getting those error :-
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://staging.backend.devasmriti.com/api/events' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
and after that this axios error

AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code

i want to fetch data but all the time i anm getting those error one more error i am getting after it

```
   GET https://staging.backend.com/api/events net::ERR_FAILED 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The 504 Gateway Timeout error means that either your HTTP server or PHP configuration (or both) exceeds the allowed time for processing a request.

When that happens, your Laravel application cannot deliver the headers that define your CORS policy. This will result in CORS errors for XMLHttpRequests.

You need to look into why your HTTP server or PHP script times out, to resolve this issue.

Comment: thanks Repox for your help i will try to figure out my https server and php script